# why we are using 2 wired connections in can bus

Tags: communication, can

I am software engineer student and I am doing researching about electric cars also how communication works in electric cars. So I was trying to find answer for,

**why everyone using 2 wired connections ( CAN High & Low ) for can bus. Can we use only CAN High or CAN Low?** and why we could use Can High and Low.

I was doing some researching but can't find exact answer. So I want to ask here.

For example I was reading this informations.

- [Easy Steps for Detecting Permanent Shorts in a HS-CAN Bus](https://www.eeweb.com/easy-steps-for-detecting-permanent-shorts-in-a-hs-can-bus/)
- [Practical tips: CAN-Bus](https://www.kmpdrivetrain.com/paddleshift/practical-tips-can-bus/)
- [CAN high / CAN low](https://support.squarell.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/94/7/can-high--can-low)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The search key to use for finding info is [differential signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling).

Comment: Cool. I will try to find exact answer. If I find some 'll write here.

Comment: It's a basic data signal concept, not unique to CAN but also used by RS-485 and other serial buses. There will be data communication and CAN books explaining it. And it's not really hard to grasp: by measuring the differntial between two voltages instead of a single absolute voltage level, we get a bus with vastly improved immunity characteristics. That's about it...

Comment: technically speaking it is 3 wire

Comment: 3 wire ? What you mean by that , So sorry to asking but I am new at this area still learning new things so I think I could ask.

Comment: Can also requires a 0V wire.

Comment: All data communication buses require a 0V.

Comment: @Lundin -  transformer coupled ones don't need a 0V reference, nor do fiber optic.

Comment: @Kartman And how do you intend to supply the secondary? Surely not through some V+ and ground signals?

Comment: CAN (Controler Area Network) is chosen for several reasons. It is very reliable, it can be made fault tolerant. CAN is a multi-master network. It uses CSMA/CD+AMP (Carrier Sense Multiple Access/Collision Detection with Arbitration on Message Priority). Before sending a message the CAN node checks if the bus is busy. It also uses collision detection.CAN is a multi-master network. It uses CSMA/CD+AMP (Carrier Sense Multiple Access/Collision Detection with Arbitration on Message Priority). Before sending a message the CAN node checks if the bus is busy. It also uses collision detection.

Comment: @Lundin - it is unclear to me what you are referring to.

Comment: @Kartman It means that a non-isolated CAN bus uses CANH, CANL, GND and optional shield. But an isolated CAN bus uses CANH, CANL, GND, V+ and optional shield. The "secondary" (isolators, optocouplers etc) needs to be supplied from somewhere, so you don't get fewer signals just by switching to galvanic isolation, you get more signals.

Comment: @Gil Not sure what your random copy/paste is good for, but taken from some questionable Internet source often means it is incorrect. CAN does not have collisions, so it uses CSMA/CA. Collision detection implies discarding the message and try again, using backoff periods etc like Ethernet. CAN does not discard messages when multiple nodes try to send at once so there is no collision but arbitration and lower priority messages yielding.  Also there are no masters in CAN so it isn't a multi-master network.

Comment: When a message is sent the dominant signal goes through. When sending the sender always monitors the buss and if it does not reflect what it is sending it shuts down thereby detecting a collision and this also implements non destructive argration. When the sender detects a collision is aborts its message and tries again later up to n times.